# Is there a way to return early in deferred promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

So I have a promise which contains multiple checks like this

```
function test(){
    var deferred = q.defer()
    var passed = false
    if(!passed){
        deferred.reject("Don't proceed")
        //return
    } else {
        if(!passed){
            deferred.reject("Don't proceed")
        } else {
            if(!passed){
                deferred.reject("Don't proceed")
            } else {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    console.log("Hello");
                    deferred.resolve()
                }, 100);
            }
        }
    }
    return deferred.promise
}
```

This looks bad because there is a pyramid at the bottom. I'm wondering is there something like return in 'q' which can make the code look better? For example like this:

```
function test(){
    var deferred = q.defer()
    var passed = false
    if(!passed){
        deferred.reject("Don't proceed")
        return
    }
    if(!passed){
        deferred.reject("Don't proceed")
        return
    }
    if(!passed){
        deferred.reject("Don't proceed")
        return
    } 
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Hello");
        deferred.resolve()
    }, 100);
    return deferred.promise
}
```

This definitely doesn't work because it returned before promise is returned, but I'm wondering is there something like a return?

Comment: Why not use `if (passed)` to continue and then at the very end of the function, you can have one test to see if you should reject or not.

Comment: in every condition you can return the deferred.promise instead of only return. It would be messy though.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to create a single deferred, that could be rejected from multiple parts of your function, and which you would need to return at every exit point.
Instead, code with separate promises, one for each branch of control flow you have. You can use [`Q.reject`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qrejectreason) and the [`Q.Promise` constructor](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qpromiseresolver) - avoid the deprecated deferred pattern. Your function would then look like this:

```
function test() {
    var deferred = q.defer()
    var passed = false
    if (!passed)
        return Q.reject("Don't proceed");
    if (!passed)
        return Q.reject("Don't proceed");
    if (!passed)
        return Q.reject("Don't proceed");
    // else
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("Hello");
            resolve();
        }, 100);
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you can wrap your `test` function in [`Q.fbind`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisefbindargs-deprecated), so that instead of writing `return Q.reject(…);` you could just do `throw …;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(){
    var deferred = q.defer()
    var passed = false
    if(true){
        deferred.reject(new Error("Don't proceed1"))
        return deferred.promise
    }
    if(!passed){
        deferred.reject(new Error("Don't proceed2"))
        return deferred.promise
    }
    if(!passed){
        deferred.reject(new Error("Don't proceed3"))
        return deferred.promise
    } 
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Hello");
        deferred.resolve()
    });
    return deferred.promise
}
```

I think this is the best way, thank to Bergi

Comment: The function needs to return a promise first, so it returns a promise first then reject it, you can't do `return deferred.reject()` because it doesn't return a promise and it will throw error. Doing this avoids the pyramid.

Comment: But you can simply `deferred.reject(); return deferred.promise;` (if you don't want to use the even simpler version from my answer). There's no need for an asynchronous callback.