# Idiomatically handling pre-conditions with ES6 Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I am new to ES6 Promises and have been doing research. I have some code executing in NodeJS that does some async work, but I have a few pre-conditions that must be checked first. I'm seeking the **idiomatic best-practice** for dealing with this (if such a thing exists) along with some reasoning. I hope to gain an understanding, as I already have working code.

Consider the following fictional snippet:

```
function doStuff(data, cb) {
     if (!data) {
         return cb(new Error("Don't be an idiot"));
     }

     externalLibrary.doSomethingCallbackAsync(data, cb);
}
```

Were I to translate this into promise-land, I see two options.

---

**Option 1**, I can include the pre-condition in the promise.

```
function doStuff(data){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!data) {
            return reject(new Error("Don't be an idiot"));
        }

        externalLibrary.doSomethingCallbackAsync(data, function(err, newData) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve(newData);
        });
    });
}
```

---

**Option 2**, I can run the pre-condition prior to the promise. I'm not certain I understand the intent of `Promise.reject()`, but it seems to fit the bill here by allowing me to return an immediately rejected promise.

```
function doStuff(data){
    if (!data) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error("Don't be an idiot"));
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        externalLibrary.doSomethingCallbackAsync(data, function(err, newData) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve(newData);
        });
    });
}
```

---

I prefer **Option 2** for readability reasons, but I don't fully understand `Promise.reject()` and I am concerned that **Option 2** is misusing it. Just to reiterate, I am looking for a best-practice solution.

Comment: I'm sure that this is just an example, but don't forget that it's better to use error objects instead of a plain string for these types of error messages if this was a real function.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Qantas94Heavy. It is merely an example, I typed it freehand and got lazy :) Update to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not certain I understand the intent of `Promise.reject()`, but it seems to fit the bill here

You've understood it correctly. It's explicitly made for use cases such as this. Go for it, it *is* the best practice.

The advantage of Option 2 is that it works much cleaner with APIs that already do return promises (think `return externalLibrary.doSomethingAsync(data)`), and has less chance to fall for the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572).

Comment: See also [Is there a way to return early in deferred promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31934181/1048572) and [if-else flow in promise](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26599798/1048572) for more best-practice code examples.

Comment: Thanks for the succinct answer and the extra links @Bergi!